# crystal report remove wrap text next column white space

Tags: c#, report

Hello i create ledger party statement can any body remove the wrap text next column white space remove example is below mention.[image]

[image]

i also try to suppress blank selection, but not it can not work, please give me example how to remover this red circle white space or line

Comment: if they are in different section then in section expert check the option "underlay following section"

Comment: Add section below and shift the debit part to new detail section and then try "underlay following section"

Comment: you mean insert new detail part and shift the debit on new detail section, i try but it is not work

Comment: yes, have you apply "underlay following section" first detaill section